# Adding text labels to ggplot2 scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, scatter-plot

Is there a good way easy way to add text labels to the circles on the graph?  I haven't able to do it using the directlabels package because I get the error:

Error in direct.label.ggplot(p, "first.qp") : Need colour aesthetic to infer default direct labels."

Here is the graph:
[image: What I have at the moment]

And here is the code that I've been using:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(directlabels)
#my data set:
oc <- read.csv("http://www.columbia.edu/~mad2200/oc.csv")
oc$percent_women <- oc$W_employment/(oc$M_employment+oc$W_employment)
oc$size <- oc$W_employment+oc$M_employment
p <- ggplot(oc, aes(M_w_earnings, W_w_earnings, label = as.character(Occupational.Group)))
p + geom_point(aes(size = size, colour=percent_women)) + scale_size_continuous(range=c(0,30)) + #scale_area()+
#geom_point(aes(colour = oc$percent_women)) + 
coord_equal() +
scale_colour_gradient(high = "red")+
ylim(700, 1700) +
xlim(700, 1700) +
geom_abline(slope=1) +
labs(title = "Income Disparity by Occupation and Gender") +
ylab("Women's Weekly Earnings in $") +
xlab("Men's Weekly Earnings in $")
```

Comment: What mnel asked. And also look into `geom_text()` in `ggplot2` for text annotations.

Comment: @Maiasaura, I think he wants to annotate the Occipational.Group (given the definiition of p) (I had asked what text to label with)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Add `geom_text(aes(label=Occupational.Group), size=3)` to the plot.  You'll need to play with the size though.

[image]

Comment: Great thanks! This worked well.  I was also fooling around some more with adding the geom_dl to the plot and I got the labels on, but found it really difficult to change the font size.  This is a much better solution.